# Messages not being received for NServiceBus on RabbitMQ

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, microservices, nservicebus

I have a backend where a simple string object event is being published. The event publishing service (SimpleSend) do show up in the rabbitmq dashboard but not the receiving/handling (SimpleReceive) service's. Also the event is not being received by the handler.

The event being as below

```
    public class TransTest : IEvent
{
    public string TimeSlots { get; set; }

    public TransTest(string timeSlots)
    {
        TimeSlots = timeSlots;
    }
}
```

And the dependency injection on the startup (dotnet 5 was upgraded to 6) is as follows.
(Mind you that I have tested this on a local rabbitmq and a hosted one)

```
        services.AddSingleton<IMessageSession>(provider =>
        {
            var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("SimpleSender");
            endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<SystemJsonSerializer>();
            endpointConfiguration.AutoSubscribe();
            var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();
            //transport.ConnectionString("host=localhost");
            transport.ConnectionString("host=rabbitmq;username=dev;password=dev");
            transport.UseConventionalRoutingTopology(QueueType.Quorum);
            //transport.UseDirectRoutingTopology(
            //    QueueType.Classic,
            //    exchangeNameConvention: () => "name_event_bus"
            //);
           
            transport.Routing().RouteToEndpoint(typeof(TransTest), "SimpleReceiver");
            endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

            var endpointInstance = NServiceBus.Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return endpointInstance;
        });
```

I publish the event through an API endpoint like below

```
        [HttpGet("/Test")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetTestTrans()
    {

        var sendOptions = new SendOptions();
        sendOptions.SetDestination("SimpleReceiver");
        Console.WriteLine("Sending message to calendar");
        var saga = new TransTest("MESSAGE");
        await _messageSession.Publish(saga);

        return Ok();
    }
```

The receiving/handling services DI is as below, implemented in the startup,

```
            services.AddSingleton<IMessageSession>(provider =>
        {
            var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("SimpleReceiver");
            endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<SystemJsonSerializer>();
            endpointConfiguration.AutoSubscribe();
            var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();
            //transport.ConnectionString("host=localhost");
            
            transport.ConnectionString("host=rabbitmq;username:dev;password:dev");
            transport.UseConventionalRoutingTopology(QueueType.Quorum);
            //transport.UseDirectRoutingTopology(
            //    QueueType.Classic,
            //    exchangeNameConvention: () => "name_event_bus"
            //    );

            endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
            var endpointInstance = NServiceBus.Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return endpointInstance;
        });
```

and the handler for this is as below.

```
    public class SagaTimeSlotsHandler : IHandleMessages<TransTest>
{
    static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger<SagaTimeSlotsHandler>();
    public async Task Handle(TransTest message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SAGA HANDLED");
        Console.WriteLine(message.TimeSlots);
        log.Info($"Hello from {nameof(SagaTimeSlotsHandler)}");
        Task.Completed;
    }
}
```

I have attached a screenshot of the rabbitmq dashboard below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the `Endpoint.Start` call in your receiver is never executed. It is inside of the factory method for `IMessageSession` but nothing in that application ever resolves `IMessageSession` and so the factory method is never run.

To add NServiceBus to a host and ensure that it is properly started, you should use the [`UseNServiceBus(..)` method](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/extensions-hosting#configuration) found in the [NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting/).

If you are hosting an NServiceBus endpoint in a web application there are [samples showing how to do that](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/web-application).

Comment: this is most probably the cause